# What is Segue in IOS development?

Tags: ios, iphone, segue

I want to know about the segue and the usage of this in IOS.i am new to IOS platform.I only have a basic programming knowledge in IOS. I want to understand the segues in IOS. Any helps will appreciable.

Comment: What's your specific question? There's Google for that.

Comment: sorry but SO isn't a replacement for documentation/books/tutorial or even google

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A segue represents the transition from one scene to the next scene, such as when one scene slides over another. Refer this link

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_storyboard/Chapters/AboutStoryboards.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014225-CH41-SW1

Comment: THANKS FOR YOUR HELP, thanks brother... Peoples like you are the best teachers for beginers like us.. :)
The guys dislike the questions are the people are so busy to dislike begineers post...
Anywau thanks dear :)

Answer (score 1):

To understand the concept and usage of segues please read [this](http://www.appcoda.com/storyboards-ios-tutorial-pass-data-between-view-controller-with-segue/) and [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/113388/storyboards-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-1) article.These two articles have step by step guide for the beginners.